# Oracle tns-listener security

Tags: oracle, security, tns

I noticed setting a tns-listener password in Oracle 8.1.7* ("SECURITY=ON"), the SIDs are anyway enumerable (via "Command=status"). According to you, is firewall filtering the only possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 – Check the DB listener status

```
   lsnrctl status
```

Notice that the listener you want (in our case “orcl”) is not showing.

Step 2 – Login via sqlplus

```
   sqlplus sys/oracle as sysdba
```

Sqlplus gave us this error message:

```
   Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed
```

Step 3 – Go into the Windows Event Viewer (eventvwr.exe)

Under “Windows Logs”, right click on Application and select “Clear Log”. Do the same for System.

It may also be wise to right click on Application and select Properties. Then, under “Log Size” select the following option under “When maximum log size is reached”: “Overwrite events as needed”. This should prevent the log from maxing out and causing the DB not to start.

In Windows Vista and higher, you can execute the following command to clear the Application log:

```
   wevtutil cl Application
```

Step 4 – Login via sqlplus

```
   sqlplus sys/oracle as sysdba
```

You should now be able to login with no error messages.

Step 5 - Check the DB listener status

```
   lsnrctl status
```

You should now see your listener running.

Step 6 – Start UCM

UCM should now start up.

For a more in-depth answer to this question you can read my full [blog post](http://www.redstonecontentsolutions.com/5/post/2011/01/tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor-error-message-of-the-monthjanuary.html).